# What's the difference between お待ちになる and 待たれる?

Tags: verbs, honorifics

I know they're both polite ways to use a verb, but my materials never taught me what unique traits each one has. Is it just the tone, or is there more to it?

Comment: 待たれる is 可能形. Which is ability form of that verb 持つ。
お待ちになる　is honorific language.

Comment: @BirkanAras 待たれる is not a form of 持つ, but of 待つ. It can be honorific or passive. See http://forum.koohii.com/viewtopic.php?pid=130286#p130286 for some discussion.

Comment: @BirkanAras:  In addition to what snailplane said, `待たれる` is also not 可能形.  The 可能形 of `待つ` is `待てる`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

お…になる sounds more respectful than …れる to me.  In particular, when used to ask for the listener to do something in speech (for example at a restaurant), こちらでお待ちになってください is fine, but こちらで待たれてください sounds impolite (not respectful enough) to me.  I do not know whether this difference is counted as “just the tone” or not.

Comment: I agree that `お〜になる` is more often used when speaking *to* the person, and `（ら）れる` is more often used when speaking *about* the person.  At least how I've seen it.